# Access settings from component in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

As title said I'm access settings from component using Settings model in my plugin but got blank result instead the current stored at DB. This is what I'm doing. First this is my `fields.yaml` file definition:

```
fields:
    sandbox_enabled:
      label: Activar modo Sandbox?
      type: checkbox
      default: false
    ppal_fee:
      label: Cargo de PayPal
      type: text
    ppal_discount:
      label: Descuento por transferencias
      type: text
    ppal_app_id_sandbox:
      label: PayPal Sandbox App ID (*)
      type: text
    ppal_developer_account:
      label: PayPal Developer Account Email Address (*)
      type: text
    ppal_api_username_sandbox:
      label: PayPal Username API Credentials (Sandbox) (*)
      type: text
    ppal_api_password_sandbox:
      label: PayPal Password API Credentials (Sandbox) (*)
      type: text
    ppal_api_signature_sandbox:
      label: PayPal Signature API Credentials (Sandbox) (*)
      type: text
    ppal_rest_client_id_sandbox:
      label: PayPal REST API Username Credentials (Sandbox) (*)
      type: text
    ppal_rest_client_secret_sandbox:
      label: PayPal REST API Secret Credentials (Sandbox) (*)
      type: text
```

Second, `alomicuba.recharge.settings` record values at DB:

```
{
     "sandbox_enabled":"1",
     "ppal_fee":"0.029",
     "ppal_discount":"0.30",
     "ppal_app_id_sandbox":"",
     "ppal_developer_account":"",
     "ppal_api_username_sandbox":"",
     "ppal_api_password_sandbox":"",
     "ppal_api_signature_sandbox":"",
     "ppal_rest_client_id_sandbox":"",
     "ppal_rest_client_secret_sandbox":""
  }
```

And finally how I'm getting the values for settings in my component:

```
public function onAmountChange()
{
    // The user amount
    $amount = post('amount');

    if (empty($amount))
    {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Por favor introduzca un valor.'));
    }

    $toReload = $amount - ($amount * Settings::get('ppal_fee') - Settings::get('ppal_discount'));
    $this->page["confirmation_text"] = $toReload;
}
```

But it's not working since this two values `Settings::get('ppal_fee')`, `Settings::get('ppal_discount')` comes empty, why? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you specified following line of code on top?

```
use Alomicuba\Recharge\Models\Settings;
```

if you have specified then try using following line of code:

```
$settings = Settings::instance();

$settings->ppal_fee;
```

all over function code look like this

```
public function onAmountChange()
{
    // The user amount
    $amount = post('amount');

    if (empty($amount))
    {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Por favor introduzca un valor.'));
    }
    $settings = Settings::instance();

    $toReload = $amount - ($amount * $settings->ppal_fee - $settings->ppal_discount);
    $this->page["confirmation_text"] = $toReload;
}
```

refer https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/settings#reading-settings

Comment: Upssss!!!! My code is just fine, the problem was a typo in the `use` statement since I've this `use Alomicuba\Webservices\Models\Settings` which belongs to another plugin, changing to this `use Alomicuba\Recharge\Models\Settings` solve my issues, thx @anand-patel

Comment: i thought so you have not included that class .anyway your problem get solved.